# KMM: Only requires running Xcode in Rosetta Mode on Apple Silicon

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Currently, I cannot deploy and compile my kmm project in Xcode (M1 chip), the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode' not found in project ':shared'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 467ms
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

But when I use the Rosetta mode，it will succeed, what is the cause of this problem, and how can I solve it once and for all?

This is part of my build.gradle content：

```
build.gradle(android part)>>>

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
```

And my jdk is `Amazon Corretto 17`

> build.gradle(shared part)
> kotlin {
> android()
>
> ```
>     val iosTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget = when {
>         System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true -> ::iosArm64
>         else -> ::iosX64
>     }
>
>     iosTarget("ios") {
>         binaries {
>             framework {
>                 baseName = "kmm_shared"
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     targets.withType<KotlinNativeTarget> {
>         compilations.get("main").kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xexport-kdoc"
>         compilations.get("main").kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime"
>     }
>
>     sourceSets {
>         val commonMain by getting {
>
>             kotlin.srcDir("$buildDir/generated-apis/src/commonMain/kotlin")
>             dependencies {
>                 with(Deps.Supernaturals) {
>                     implementation(kotlinFs)
>                 }
>                 with(Deps.Ktor) {
>                     api(clientCore)
>                     api(clientJson)
>                     api(clientSerialization)
>                 }
>                 with(Deps.Kotlinx) {
>                     implementation(coroutinesCore)
>                     implementation(serializationCore)
>                     implementation(dateTime)
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         val commonTest by getting {
>             dependencies {
>                 with(Deps.TestCommon) {
>                     implementation(kotlin(testCommon))
>                     implementation(kotlin(testAnnotationsCommon))
>                 }
>                 with(Deps.Mockk) {
>                     implementation(mockkCommon)
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         val androidMain by getting {
>             dependencies {
>                 with(Deps.Ktor) {
>                     implementation(clientCio)
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         val androidTest by getting {
>             dependencies {
>                 with(Deps.Junit) {
>                     implementation(kotlin(testJunit))
>                     implementation(junit)
>                 }
>                 with(Deps.Mockk) {
>                     implementation(mockk)
>
>                 }
>                 with(Deps.Kotlinx) {
>                     implementation(coroutinesTest)
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         val iosMain by getting {
>             dependencies {
>                 with(Deps.Ktor) {
>                     api(clientIos)
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         val iosTest by getting
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please provide content of your `build.gradle` file. Also which JDK is used by Xcode? you can check it by adding `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` into your **Run Script Phase**

Comment: Thanks. And I have provide some message for my project. Because I’m not very familiar with build.gradle of KMM, I don’t know which piece of content I need to provide. It would be great if I could explain it in detail.

Comment: android `build.gradle` has nothing to do with the iOS app, please replace it with content of your shared module `build.gradle`

Comment: Alright, I have provided it.